# ‘d’ undeclared (first use in this function)

Tags: c

It should return "d" because it's a counter. But it's not declared. I'm stacked on this question. When i declare "d" before the code, it has no sense.

I have this code :

```
int collatz(const int number){
  for(int d = 0; number > 1; d++){
    int number;
    if(number % 2 == 0){
      number = number / 2;
    }else{
      number = number * 3 + 1;
    }
  }
  return d;   
}
```

Comment: You declare the variable d in for loop. You should declare and define it in the function collatz block, outside of the for.

Comment: `d` only exists until the `for` loop ends.

Comment: The `number` you declare in the loop is not the same as the `number` parameter.

Comment: But when i'm doing it gives me an error.  error: ‘d’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Werror=uninitialized]
   return d;

Comment: Also:  `number = number / 2` is not valid with `const int number`.  Use `int number`.

Answer (score 1):

1. `d` is declared inside of `for` loop and limited by it's scope. Move declaration out of loop.
2. `int number` in scope of `for` loop shadows parameter `number`. Use parameter as variable.

```c
int collatz(int number)
{
  int d = 0;
  for(; number > 1; d++) {
    if(number % 2 == 0){
      number = number / 2;
    }else{
      number = number * 3 + 1;
    }
  }
  return d;   
}
```

`while` loop looks more readable:

```c
int collatz(int number)
{
  int d = 0;
  while (number > 1) {
    if(number % 2 == 0){
      number = number / 2;
    }else{
      number = number * 3 + 1;
    }
    d++;
  }
  return d;   
}
```

Comment: I cant do like this because const int number is necessarily to write in the task. It's a condition

Comment: @REQUIEMSONG Wierd requirement. You can write `int n = number;` before loop and use `n` instead of `number`.